# How to import a new powershell cmdlet?

Tags: powershell

I have just downloaded the `Register-TemporaryEvent` cmdlet from http://poshcode.org/2205 and placed it in my powershell profile directory near the `$profile` script.

How do I create a new command `Register-TemporaryEvent` which would be bound to this script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PowerShell, you can execute scripts as commands if they are placed in directories contained in the 'PATH' environment variable. To see what directories are in the Path, you can use:

```
$env:Path -split ';'| sort
```

You could modify the path permanently from Windows' System Properties to include the location of your scripts, or you could temporarily modify the path from within your profile or script. In your particular case, you could add the following to your profile to add the profile directory to the path:

```
$ScriptRoot = Split-Path $SCRIPT:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

if(($env:Path -split ';') -notcontains $ScriptRoot) {
    $env:Path += ';' + $ScriptRoot
}
```

You can then run the command as:

```
PS >$timer = New-Object Timers.Timer
PS >Register-TemporaryEvent $timer Disposed { [Console]::Beep(100,100) }
```

Note: When tab completing, it will complete as `Register-TemporaryEvent.ps1`, but you can remove the '.ps1' and it will still work.

Comment: Is that still true? I have a folder within my PATH with .ps1 files in it, the .ps1 extension in my PATHEXT, and when I try to invoke the script by its name, I get "The term 'foo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program." (but it works from a cmd prompt)

Comment: It has always worked for me in all PowerShell versions from v2 through v5. If you enter `$env:PATH` at the powershell prompt, do you see the folder there? Maybe PATH wasn't added permanently or explorer.exe hasn't been restarted since PATH was changed. Also, .ps1 doesn't need to be in PATHEXT to call the script from powershell.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the content of the script file, enclose it in a function and invoke the code to create the function.

```
$sb = Get-Content .\script.ps1 | Out-String
Invoke-Expression "function Register-TemporaryEvent {`n $sb `n} "
```